# How to detect if a file empty or not in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to load data from file when program loads,but i need to detect first wether the is file is empty or not ?
When it loads it makes program infinite, so how can i detect a empty file in c++?

```
void loadfromfile(record *&newrecord, ifstream &in)
{
    in.open("records.txt", ios::binary | ios::in);
    record *temprecord = new record;
    record *tempreholder = new record;
    tempreholder = newrecord;
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        if (newrecord == nullptr)
        {
            newrecord = new record;
            in.read((char *)(&newrecord), sizeof(newrecord));
            newrecord->node = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            in.read((char *)(&temprecord), sizeof(temprecord));
            temprecord->node = nullptr;
            newrecord->node = temprecord;
        }
    }
    newrecord = tempreholder;
    in.close();
}
```

Comment: You can use `if (!(in.eof())) ` and a counter that, if it doesn't go up (the counter), the file is empty.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong